# Target class within a jquery object

Tags: jquery, object

I am trying to find a specific class within an object that contains imported page content and then get the data attached:

```
 $.get(otherHtml, function(result) {
      var currOtherHtml = $(result).find('[class^="customcontent"]');
      var otherPath = currOtherHtml.html().find('span.flpath').attr('data-fpath');
 }
```

The class I'm trying to target is this line w/in the object:

```
<span class="flpath" data-fpath="mypage_files"></span>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: change `customcontent` in `flpath`? How generic do you want this to be? `var otherPath = currOtherHtml.data('fpath')`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention: .customcontent is a wrapper div & inside of that is .flpath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` isn't a function of string. There is nothing wrong with the first line, the problem is here:

```
  var otherPath = currOtherHtml.html().find('span.flpath').attr('data-fpath');
                                   ^returns a string
```

Should be

```
  var otherPath = currOtherHtml.find('span.flpath').eq(0).attr('data-fpath');
```

Using `.html()` will return a string. You should simply use the jQuery object returned from your first line, and call find on that. `eq(0)` is equivalent to asking for the first jQuery object in the set so that you are able to access the first match's data-fpath attribute (note: `.get(0)` gets the native element).

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML content is like this:

```
<div class="customcontent">
    <span class="flpath" data-fpath="mypage_files"></span>
</div>
```

Then in your script, the `otherHtml` parameter can be combined with a data -, class selector ..., I think ... you can skip the selection of `.flpath`.

```
// @param otherHtml {Object}
// @param cssClass {String} '.customcontent'
// @param dataClass {String} 'fpath'
// @returns undefined or {String} mypage_files
function getDataOtherPath (otherHtml, cssClass, dataClass){
    $.get(otherHtml, function(result) {
        var html = $(result).find(cssClass).find('[data-' + dataClass + ']');
        return html.data(dataClass);
    }
}
```

Not tested, but it's an idea ...